# ReactJs 0.14 - Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs

Tags: reactjs

> **SOLUTION BELOW ...**

**I have an animation component:**

```
const CSSAnimation = require('./cssanimation.js');

export default class Animation extends Component {

     ..............

    componentWillMount() {
    let clientId = this.props.clientId;
    this.createSlideShow(clientId)
    }

   createSlideShow(clientId) {
    let results = [];
    slides.map(function (slide, index) {
        results.push(
            <div key={ index } className="slide" ref="slide">
            .......
            </div>
         );
    }.bind(this));
    this.setState({slideShow: results});
    let slideRef = this.refs.slide;  <--- returns undefined
    new CSSAnimation(slideRef)

     ...........................
```

---

```
    render() {
    return (
        <div id="Animation" className="datatable sam" ref="Animation">
            { this.state.slideShow }
        </div>
    )
   }
  );
 }
}
```

"cssanimation.js" is a pure javascript 3rd party file that requires only 1 thing, the node with the className of 'slide'.

The variable slideRef is not getting the refs element and is undefined.

Anyone see my error?

Thanks in Advance

---

> ***UPDATE:***
>
> I now know why I am getting the error but I do not know yet how to correct it.
> Apparently, refs are not to be used unless directly inside the render method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The error I received according to the docs occurs for one of 2 reasons:**
>
> ```
> 1. The application has multiple react modules in the build.
> 2. The ref attribute is not being used w/in the render method.
> ```

My problem was #2.

I moved the entire createSlideShow() method contents inside the render function, but then I incurred another error: ***You cannot update state w/in the render function***.

So, for me, I did away with state.slideShow and just worked with results, as follows ...

```
render() {

      let results = [];
      slides.map(function (slide, index) {
        results.push(
        <div key={ index } className="slide" ref="slide">
        .......
        </div>
      );
     }.bind(this));

   return (
        <div id="Animation" className="datatable sam" ref="Animation">
            { results }
        </div>
    )
  }


   componentDidMount() {
       let slideRef = this.refs.slide; // returns back with "slideRef = div.slide"     
       new CSSAnimation(slideRef);
   }
```